# get_post_type_object() does not work with switch_to_blog()

Tags: multisite, wp-api

the title is pretty much self-explanatory but it seems that get_post_type_object() does not work with switch_to_blog() here is the situation

I have blog A and blog B. I registered a custom post type on blog A and I wanted to update a particular post with that custom post type on blog B. So I used wp_update_post() to achieve this ( I provided ID and post_content)

However, it returned an error:

> trying to get property of non-object in ms-blogs.php on line 864.

This line contains get_post_type_object() and I did not return any object since it did not recognize that custom post type object (this is recognized on blog A)

so my code was:

```
switch_to_blog(blog A ID);
        $args = array(
            'ID' => (int) $class_data['class_post_id'],
            'post_content' => $_POST['post_content']
        );
        wp_update_post($args);
        update_post_meta($class_data['class_post_id'], XN_PREFIX . 'class_summary',     $class_data['class_summary']);
    restore_current_blog();
```

It does work but it returns above error message. Can anyone tell me what to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading blog B (thankfully) it doesn't load plugins which are active on blog A only, and `switch_to_blog()` (thankfully) doesn't do that either.

You could trigger the update by using something like the JSON API (or XML-RPC, ewwww), or you could make sure the post type is registered both on blog A and blog B. Maybe set `show_ui` to `false` on blog B so it doesn't clutter the user interface.

Comment: Just realised how fragile switch_to_blog can be ( it does not even understand taxonomies residing in blog A). Thank you for the comment. I appreciate it.